# Dynamic fields indexing on nested documents with RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

How would you handle dynamic fields indexing on nested documents so that you can query dynamic fields of a deep graph object with RavenDB?

Using the example from the documentation: http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/advanced/dynamic-fields

What if the value of a product's attribute is also a product? Think of a CMS with dynamic fields where everything is a *content* and a root entity content (for the DDD guys) may embed another one, etc (deep graph).

This is very important since, aggregating child contents instead of relating to them (like you would do in a relational database world), is one of the core concept of document databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data conforms to a pattern, such as with hierarchical data, then you can [recurse into that data](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/indexing-hierarchies) to index according to the recursion pattern.

You already found how to [index dynamic fields](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/advanced/dynamic-fields).  You can combine these techniques to get at most any pattern that you can describe.

If the data is *arbitrarily* dynamic (i.e. you have no way of knowing what the object structure is ahead of time), then you are going to have a hard time reaching any particular field because you can't describe how to access it.

You can't be arbitrarily dynamic and be completely indexable at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the Recurse function. I'm not sure it would work for my scenario. Anyways, I went another way to solve my problem and, yes my problem is about arbitrarily dynamic data. The solution I found is to use the HTTP API that comes with RavenDB.

Comment: How does using the HTTP API change what you are indexing?

Comment: Good question... the answer is that I'm not storing a C# class anymore. With the HTTP API, I can generate (at runtime - not knowing this structure before) a well defined structure (JSON object) representing the data that is nested in name/value collections (like the product example referenced) in my C# model.

Comment: I think you can still do that with either a `dynamic` or an `ExpandoObject` in c# if you want.  The http api can get unwieldy at times.  I wouldn't want to throw out the c# client just for this.

Comment: This is also what I tought at first but no, I can't. Dynamic object or ExpandoObject are not helping with building data structure at runtime. You can't iterate nested name/value collections and build the dynamic object at runtime.